# Increase the scrolling height of the scrollview

Tags: android, android-widget

is this possible for scrollview scrolls once it reached the end of the widget?

if possible can u please share the snnippets to do this.

Thanking you

Comment: do you mean like in iOS ?

Comment: @Cflex yes, canu please provide me the snippets to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look to `setOverScrollMode` in ScrollView (api 9+) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setOverScrollMode(int)

Otherwise, take a look to the implementation of pullToRefresh lib here https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this attribute : `android:fillViewport="true"`

Have a look at : [ScrollView’s handy trick](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/)

Comment: thanks for reply, actually i does not have any view at the last. i need to scroll still, is that possible?